# Convert C# Linq query to VB.Net Linq

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, signalr

I have a project where I am using Linq query in if condition to check for the condition is true or false and its working fine in my C# project. Now I have another project of mine where I want to use the same thing but the issue is this project is in vb.net and I am getting issues while converting Linq queries. My linq query in c# is like this:

```
#region Data Members

        static List<UserDetail> ConnectedUsers = new List<UserDetail>();
        static List<MessageDetail> CurrentMessage = new List<MessageDetail>();

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public void Connect(string userName)
        {
            var id = Context.ConnectionId;


            if (ConnectedUsers.Count(x => x.ConnectionId == id) == 0)
            {
                ConnectedUsers.Add(new UserDetail { ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName });

                // send to caller
                Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage);

                // send to all except caller client
                Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, userName);

            }

        }
        }
```

Its vb.net equivalent is like this:

```
#Region "Data Members"

        Shared ConnectedUsers As New List(Of UserDetail)()
        Shared CurrentMessage As New List(Of MessageDetail)()

#End Region

#Region "Methods"
Public Sub Connect(userName As String)
            Dim id = Context.ConnectionId

            If ConnectedUsers.Count(Function(x) x.ConnectionId = id) = 0 Then


                ConnectedUsers.Add(New UserDetail() With { _
                    Key .ConnectionId = id, _
                    Key .UserName = userName _
                })

                ' send to caller
                Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage)

                ' send to all except caller client

                Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, userName)
            End If

        End Sub
```

[Error screen shot is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcd4h.png)

Comment: In C#, we would say "using System.Linq;" at the top of the file to allow access to the extension methods on System.Linq.Enumerable.  Have you done whatever the vb equivalent is?

Comment: Yes I have converted whole page I have inclued these namespaces:   Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Imports SignalRChat.Common

Comment: Do you have 'Option Infer On'?  If you don't have this, then 'id' will be typed as 'Object'.

Comment: where to find this @dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution you need to do something like this:

If ConnectedUsers.AsEnumerable.Count(Function(x) x.ConnectionId = id) = 0 Then